# How can I delete a user created if a user closes the purchase window?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

The client fills in the registration form and a user is created, with a basic role, and directs them to Paypal to make the payment, here is my question: in the case that the user closes the Paypal tab without making the payment, the user is registered, and if you return to the registration link, you cannot register, because the email and user already exist, as I can do if the client closes the Paypal window, that the data registered in the DB is deleted, so that you can access to link again and register without problems?

Comment: Tip: Make a `cron`-type job to clear out stale users that never finished.

Comment: I thought about it, but there would be conflict, if the client takes 5 min on the paypal page, and the cron is executed every 3 min for example, the data that I use from the form would be erased

Comment: That's why you'd wait a very generous amount of time, at least an hour or more, if not clear them out once they're a day old, and only then. There's no way to know, authoritatively, if a tab has been closed vs. if someone just went offline briefly and will pick up later. The only way is to establish a reasonable time limit.

Comment: If you've already collected information and the user returns later, why not get them to authenticate or re-confirm their email to resume the session instead of deleting it?

Comment: That I am trying to implement, as an upgrade, to log in, and can change roles by making the payment. I think it would be the best! Thanks for the help.

Comment: It might be tricky to merge the data back in, but it can be done and from a user perspective avoids all the confusion regarding having a previously "registered" account from a failed transaction.

Comment: some shop apps separate the concept of a cart and a order so there isn't a confusion between ordered and unordered cases. Intermediate states like purchase_in_progress are probably needed to Paypal and and this could be purged with the stock returned to available after timeout but not the cart. Take care of all the edge cases.

Comment: Why want again again register?

Comment: In the end I had the user registered in a basic level, which only allows him to access so that he can increase his level when buying a product.

Comment: My main idea was that I don't create any records until I am taken to the thanks page. But I would have to change all the logic. The fastest way was to be registered, and when the purchase is finished the level will be updated.